# Old iPhone with wifi used like tablet

Tags: wifi, text, android

We recently gave our 10 year old son my old iPhone to use like an iPad. The iPhone is not activated so no cell service but has access to wifi.

Why is he unable to text his grandparents who have Android phones?

Comment: What app are you using to "text" messages?

Answer (score 6):

'Text', or more specifically SMS messaging, requires a functional phone number.

iMessage, though to the end user looks the same except for a blue background rather than green, doesn't use the 'phone' structure at all, it uses 'data', channeled by Apple ID, but if it can't send an iMessage through regular data channels, it will switch to sending by phone - if both sender & receiver have a phone number to channel through. It 'learns' this behaviour so it doesn't keep trying once it's established the recipient has no Apple ID it can route to.

You can use an iPad or SIM-less iPhone to send SMS, if the user's Apple ID lists a valid phone number on another iDevice that can be leveraged into performing the actual SMS transmission. e.g. on a Mac, the phone number listed is one belonging to an online iPhone belonging to the same Apple ID…

[image]

If a message is sent from this Mac to an Android device, the Mac in effect asks the iPhone to send it instead. As far as I'm aware [someone correct me if I'm wrong] this functionality is enabled by 'Enable messages in iCloud'.

Android devices cannot use iMessage at all, they need another method. Without a phone account to send from, iMessage's auto-switching has no alternate path, so cannot send.
This is one of the reasons for the popularity of such as WhatsApp on Android - it has no ID-based messaging, so it uses phone number-based structures instead.

Comment: Instead of WhatsApp, use [Signal](https://signal.org/) because they are not owned by Meta/Facebook and won’t violate your privacy.

Comment: @Allan - I wasn't actually recommending WhatsApp - in fact I've never used it or anything vaguely similar - but does Signal work without a phone number? […does WhatsApp work without a phone number too?]

Comment: Sorry…that was meant for the audience

Comment: @Tetsujin Not sure about Signal, but WhatsApp needs an active phone number.

Comment: @Allan Are you sure it's a good idea to give suggestions in the comment section? Because I almost felt like giving a counter proposal to Signal, which could quickly turn the comment section into a debate if other people went along.